# jquery position element relative to mouse

Tags: jquery, position, mouse

I have an element called `#text`, which fades outs on an event.

```
$('#text').animate({ opacity : 0 }, 2500);
```

On the same event I also want it to position the element at the mouse co-ords.

I've read up and not sure what I'm supposed to use, offset(), position() etc.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VagxT/4/)? I grabbed the mouse coordinates at the time of the click and set the target element's `top` and `left` properties accordingly. Note that my fiddle should be updated to take into consideration the wrapper's own offset

Answer (score 0):

I've use this tutorial to get mouse position : http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position
and `.css` to change div's position.

here is example(div is following mouse): http://jsfiddle.net/UpsyR/